# jQuery Simple Calculation not working and not showing any error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create calculator filtering it through `data-filter`. I am beginner in programming also in jquery so not be strict. I wrote script however its not working and not showing any error.

```
<form>
    <select id="kraska">
      <option value="0.99" data-filter="1">test1</option>
      <option value="4" data-filter="2">test2</option>
    </select>
    <input id="metr" type="text" />
    <button id="calculate" type="submit">Calculate</button>
    <p id="result"></p>
</form>
<p id="result"></p>
```

```js
$('#calculate').click(function(){
    if ($('#kraska').data('data-filter') == 1) {
        var result = $('#kraska').val() * $('#metr').val(); 
    };

    if ($('#kraska').data('data-filter') == 2) {
        var result = $('#kraska').val() / $('#metr').val();
    };

    $('#result').html(result)
})
```

Comment: `$('#kraska').data('data-filter')` -> `$('#kraska').data('filter')`

Comment: your button type is submit, try making it button itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a few corrections in your code:

1. When you are using `data` method for getting any data-attribute's value, you need to use the attribute name without the `data-` part.
2. You are trying to get the data-attribute's value for the select element, while you have specified them on your `option` elements. So, you need to select the `:selected` option instead.
3. I have also removed button's type `submit`, though you can handle it with `e.preventDefault()` in your click handler even if you want to keep it as a `type="submit"` button.

```js
$('#calculate').on("click", function(e){
    if ($('#kraska option:selected').data('filter') == 1) {
        var result = $('#kraska').val() * $('#metr').val(); 
    };

    if ($('#kraska option:selected').data('filter') == 2) {
        var result = $('#kraska').val() / $('#metr').val();
    };

    $('#result').html(result)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <select id="kraska">
      <option value="0.99" data-filter="1">test1</option>
      <option value="4" data-filter="2">test2</option>
    </select>
    <input id="metr" type="text" />
    <button id="calculate">Calculate</button>
    <p id="result"></p>
</form>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

U need to remove the `data-filter` to `('filter')`

```
$('#calculate').click(function(){
    if ($('#kraska').data('filter') == 1) {
        var result = $('#kraska').val() * $('#metr').val(); 
    };

    if ($('#kraska').data('filter') == 2) {
        var result = $('#kraska').val() / $('#metr').val();
    };

    $('#result').html(result)
})
```

Change the button type to button instead of submit

```
<button id="calculate" type="button">Calculate</button>
```

If its submit button form will be not submited and page will not refresh after the click.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#kraska').data('data-filter')` should be `$('#kraska').attr('data-filter')` (or `$('#kraska').data('filter')`, but unless you're using the features of `data`, no need for the other things it does).

Also note that `val` will always give you a string (if the element exists). `*` and `/` will coerce that to number for you, but it's still useful to remember, since `+` **won't** (you'll get string concatenation).

The `;` after the blocks on your `if`s are incorrect (but harmless).

**And** note that `button type="submit"` will **submit** the form if you don't prevent the default action. In your case, you don't want a submit, so you want `button type="button"`. (You can't just leave `type` off, the default `type` is `"submit"`, so you need the silly, redundant `<button type="button" ...>`.)

Answer (score 0):

Change type of your button to `button` instead of submit so the form will be not submited and page will not refresh when you click and your click event will fire :

```
<button id="calculate" type="button ">Calculate</button>
```

Also when you use `data-*` attributes you should pass just the name without `data-`, and note that you want to get the data from the selcted option so you have to add that to your selecto so it'll be :

```
$('#kraska option:selected').data('filter')
```

**NOTE:** you don't have to use `html()` when you want to affect text, it's better if you use `text()`.

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#calculate').click(function(){
    var filter = $('#kraska option:selected').data('filter');
  
    if (filter == 1) {
        var result = $('#kraska').val() * $('#metr').val();
    }

    if (filter == 2) {
        var result = $('#kraska').val() / $('#metr').val();
    }

    $('#result').text(result)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <select id="kraska">
      <option value="0.99" data-filter="1">test1</option>
      <option value="4" data-filter="2">test2</option>
    </select>
    <input id="metr" type="text" />
    <button id="calculate" type="button">Calculate</button>
    <p id="result"></p>
</form>
<p id="result"></p>
```